# iOS Beacon or Region monitoring mobile truck

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I have a mobile truck and would like the beacon or region monitoring on the iPhone to show my app in lockscreen when I am driving through city streets or send them notification. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, this is possible and very simple**, provided that the users' with your app installed are within 40-50 meters of the truck when it goes by in clear line of sight.

You simply need to make your app monitor for the beacon's identifiers using `CoreLocation`, and when you get a `didEnterRegion:` event for the beacon, fire a local notification with a message like "Mobile truck is nearby."